# Is There Something Similar To Razor Syntax For .Net 3.5?

Tags: c#, webforms, .net-3.5

Solution: in the cs file you can do something like this when data binding happens.

```
((CurrencyBox)e.Row.FindControl("addUnitCost")).Enabled = ((appInfo.UserRole == HcfRole.TeaAdmin) ? false : true);
```

I started a new job working on legacy .net code. Is there anything similar to razor syntax, where I can reference C# objects in my HTML files?

In particular, I am trying to write a simple conditional that will disable a CurrencyBox if a certain role is logged in.

```
Enabled='<%# "appInfo.UserRole" == "HcfRole.TeaAdmin" ? false : true %>'
```

In razor I could so something like

```
Enabled='<%# @("appInfo.UserRole" == "HcfRole.TeaAdmin") ? false : true %>'
```

Are there functions that can achieve the same thing?

edit: the templatefield Oleg was talking about

```
<asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Unit Cost" ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Right">
    <EditItemTemplate>
        <hcf:CurrencyBox ID="editUnitCost" runat="server" Precision="2" 
            Text='<%# Eval("SessionCostAmount") %>' ToolTip="Unit Cost" Width="90%" />
        <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="rfvEditUnitCost" runat="server" 
            ControlToValidate="editUnitCost" EnableClientScript="false" 
            ErrorMessage="Unit Cost is required." ValidationGroup="ServiceUpdateValid"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
    </EditItemTemplate>
    <ItemTemplate>
        <hcf:CurrencyBox ID="lblUnitCost" runat="server" Enabled="false" Precision="2" 
            Text='<%# Eval("SessionCostAmount") %>'  />
    </ItemTemplate>
    <FooterTemplate>
        <hcf:CurrencyBox ID="addUnitCost" runat="server" Precision="2"  
            ToolTip="Unit Cost" Width="90%" />
        <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="rfvAddUnitCost" runat="server" 
            ControlToValidate="addUnitCost" EnableClientScript="false" 
            ErrorMessage="Unit Cost is required." ValidationGroup="ServiceAddValid" />
    </FooterTemplate>
</asp:TemplateField>
```

Comment: you talking of specific technology - .net mvc. But we don't know what technology are you using now, the one you call "legacy". Is this asp.net? Web forms?

Comment: those two examples don't look very different ... the second one looks very wrong for an example of razor code. But ultimately, if you want to use razor, you should update to a current framework and use razor. No, it doesn't work on very old frameworks.

Comment: It seems to me that you are using ASP.NET Web Forms. If that assumption is correct there are two ways to achieve what you need: 1) use code-behind file; 2) use data binding like this (appInfo should be public/protected field or property of your control/page) <asp:CheckBox runat="server" ID="checkbox1" Enabled="<%# appInfo.UserRole != WebApplication1.HcfRole.TeaAdmin ? true : false %>" Text="Checkbox" />

Comment: I am using webforms.

Comment: I also edited my mock razor syntax to hopefully be more accurate. I do not have a version of visual studio capable of supporting razor so I was just writing some (very) dummy code. Upgrading the framework is way beyond the scope of my job marc. I am making some pretty minor edits to an existing site which is currently live.

Comment: thank you oleg. I altered the code behind the file but for whatever reason one of the fields in the gridview is not switching to read only (the rest of the fields are) so I am manually editing the HTML for that particular element. I can't figure out the syntax to specifically target it, since the display lists the whole gridview as one element and does not give me a specific tag to disable specific textfields.

Comment: Is your grid view data bound? If so there should be something like <asp:templatefield elements. One of them is your element of interest. Each row of the grid view is bound to an item who's properties can be accessed by Eval function. It accepts property name as argument. I should be able to use it to determine if your element should be enabled.

Comment: <FooterTemplate>
                                        <hcf:CurrencyBox ID="addUnitCost" runat="server" Precision="2"  
                                            ToolTip="Unit Cost" Width="90%" />
                                        <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="rfvAddUnitCost" runat="server" 
                                            ControlToValidate="addUnitCost" EnableClientScript="false" 
                                            ErrorMessage="Unit Cost is required." ValidationGroup="ServiceAddValid" />
                                    </FooterTemplate>

Comment: I added the entire templatefield in an edit to the original post. the footer above is what I'm trying to disable. like I said earlier I disabled the gridview in the cs file but that particular footer, and only that particular element, did not switch to read only.

Comment: hey I figured out how to reference the element in the cs file.

Comment: Its all about posting right tags